# Why using `dpkg -x` killed my 19.04 system?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, 19.04

I have just killed my 19.04 system.

I was running `sudo apt-get upgrade` and wanted to install `atop` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/atop) for monitoring purposes without interruption of upgrade process.

So I decided to download the package and extract it to the file-system with `dpkg -x` by commands below (**do not try them on real 19.xx system**!):

```
apt download atop
sudo dpkg -x atop_..._amd64.deb /
```

and then I can't use all the commands including `sudo` and `apt`.

This was a VM, so I have a snapshot. Reported [bug 1843476](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1843476) to LaunchPad about 19.04 and 19.10.

But what was wrong with my method?

I have used it before on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS without problems.
Of course after running `dpkg -x` I have used `sudo apt install` to install the package in normal way to have it listed in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Comment: NOT trying to do what apt does automatically might be a good start.  Just saying.  (you should let `apt` and `dpkg` handle extraction and install manually to avoid file clobbering...)

Comment: @ThomasWard I got exact answer when tried to fix and diagnose the problem - `dpkg -x` has killed `/lib -> /usr/lib` symlink and made system broken. It is a serious bug, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On freshly installed system `/lib` is a symlink to the `/usr/lib`:

> ```
> $ ls -l /lib
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 30 02:24 /lib -> usr/lib
> ```

**But the `dpkg -x` has overwritten `/lib` symlink with new contents**.

On the killed system it now contains only one folder (from `atop` [package contents](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/amd64/atop/filelist)):

> ```
> /lib/systemd/system-sleep/atop-pm
> /lib/systemd/system/atop.service
> /lib/systemd/system/atopacct.service
> ```

So the system can't find libraries.

I have solved this problem by booting LiveCD, mounting problematic system and recreating the symlink:

```
cd /media/user/problematic-disk/
sudo mv lib/* usr/lib
sudo rmdir lib
sudo ln -s usr/lib lib
```

and finally reinstall the package with `sudo apt install --reinstall atop`.

---

Notes:
1. the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS are not affected because of the fact that they do not have symlinks on the `/` level (except kernel and initrd).
2. **the `dpkg -x` method should be used very carefully (as last chance to fix the things) and not be used at all on 19.04 and newer versions because of the many symlinks on the top-level (`bin -> usr/bin`, `lib -> usr/lib`, `lib32 -> usr/lib32`, `lib64 -> usr/lib64`, `libx32 -> usr/libx32`, `sbin -> usr/sbin`)**.